# add a button to a programmatically created uitableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, delegates

I want my swift code to to place a button in the first tableview cell. My code is using all code and no storyboard. I don't know what to place in the 2 tableview funcs datasource and delegate. The button should not trigger any action the button should just be in the first cell.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        <#code#>
    }
    

    
    
   
    var tble = UITableView()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        [tble].forEach{
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
        }
        tble.dataSource = self
        tble.delegate = self
        tble.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
           
            
            tble.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tble.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tble.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier:  0.8),
            tble.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier:  1),
            
            
        ])
  
     
    }
    
 
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Create class from UITableViewCell
2- register the cell to the tableView
3- use tableView dequeue with identifier for index in tableviewcellforrow function

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        let cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 30))
        cell.addSubview(cellButton)
        # put other logic
    }
    else {
        # put other logic
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

I hope it will help you. Sorry, I actually didn't check it in XCode, but it is the skeleton.